# C++ Looping over a map - disappearing objects

Tags: c++, std

So, a rather curious bug I found in my code that I have a hard time understanding. I have an std::map in which I store some information. When I loop over it the first time, everything appears fine, but the second time, data is missing.

First of, I use a struct and a class like so:

```cpp
struct Eng::Pixel{
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
    };

class Eng::Edge{
public:
enum EdgeType { INTER, INTRA};
EdgeType type;
}

class Eng::Cluster{
public:
std::map<Pixel, std::vector<Edge>> trans;
}
```

Basicly, a cluster contains a map of pixels. Each pixel in this map contains transitions spots called edges. Each Pixel can have more than one edge - and an edge can be of the type inter(0) or intra (1). Please note, that some namespaces may be missing, as I am trying to simplify my problem as much as possible.

When I loop over the code:

```cpp
std::vector<Cluster> resClusters = this->GenerateClusters();

for(Cluster cluster : resClusters) //For a given cluster in clusters
        {
            this->CreateIntraEdges(cluster); //Create our intra edges. Succeeds.
            std::cout << "Cluster: " << cluster << std::endl; //Prints the bounds of the cluster.
            std::cout << "Cluster has " << cluster.trans.size() << " transition pixels." << std::endl; //Prints the keys of the map jsut fine. 
            for (const auto& p : cluster.trans ) //For each member of the map
            {
                for(Edge ed : p.second) //For each edge from std::vector<Edge>
                {
                    std::cout << ed.type << " Start: " << ed.s << " End: "<< ed.e << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

This prints fine:

```cpp
Cluster has 6 transition pixels.
0 Start: {2,14} End: {2,15}
1 Start: {2,14} End: {5,14}
1 Start: {2,14} End: {14,0}
1 Start: {2,14} End: {14,6}
1 Start: {2,14} End: {14,8}
1 Start: {2,14} End: {14,14}
0 Start: {5,14} End: {5,15}
...
```

However, run the loop again, without the this->CreateIntraEdges, and we get this:

```cpp
Second run! 
Cluster: Min: {0,0} Max: {14,14}
Cluster has 6 transition pixels.
0 Start: {2,14} End: {2,15}
0 Start: {5,14} End: {5,15}
0 Start: {14,0} End: {15,0}
0 Start: {14,6} End: {15,6}
0 Start: {14,8} End: {15,8}
0 Start: {14,14} End: {15,14}
0 Start: {14,14} End: {14,15}
...
```

Now, if you want to see the CreateIntraEdge as well, here you go:

```cpp
    void CreateIntraEdges(Cluster& c)
    {
        for (const auto& p1 : c.trans ) //For each object in the map.
        {
            for (const auto& p2 : c.trans ) //For each object in the map
            {
                if(p1.first == p2.first)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                auto [path, weight] = this->GetPath(c, p1.first, p2.first); //See if the two edges can connect.
                if(path.size() > 0)
                {
                    Edge newedge;
                    newedge.Set(p1.first, p2.first, weight, Edge::INTRA);
                    c.trans[p1.first].push_back(newedge); //Push it back onto the std::vector<Edge> for the pixel p1.first
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How come that the loop can no longer see edges where the type is 1? Is it because of the auto?

Since the map uses a custom struct, I haven't implemented an iterator. Can this be the root of the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create *copies* of many objects...

```
std::vector<Cluster> resClusters = this->GenerateClusters();
```

Here `resCluster` is a copy, changes to it will not be stored in `this` (if you have a vector there).

Same with

```
for(Cluster cluster : resClusters)
```

Here `cluster` is a *copy* of the elements in the vector. Changes to `cluster` will be lost once the loop iterates or ends.

You probably want references, at least for the loop:

```
for(Cluster& cluster : resClusters)
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes the solution we're looking for, is right under our noses. I can accept your answer in 3 minutes :)